# Why is $ y $ the argument of $ e^z $?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm having a hard time understanding how come $y$ is the argument of $e^z$. I know $e^x$ is the real part and it makes sense why this is the modulus. But all proofs i've found about the $ e^z=e^xe^{iy} $, just doesn't make any sense to me.

Truly hope some of you can clarify this.

I need a thoroughly guidance, sense this is a key element for later uses in the complex numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Law of exponents](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/exponent-laws.html) $x^{a+b}=x^a x^b$

Comment: But does that law really say anything about the argument of the complex number z?

Comment: $y$ is the argument of $e^z$, and the argument of $z$ is another thing to consider

Answer (score 2):

Let $z = x+iy$, then $e^z = e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy} = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)$ by Euler.
So the modulus is $e^x$ and the argument is $y$, not $e^{iy}$.

Note that this means that lines parallel to the real-axis (so with constant imaginary part $y$) are mapped by $e^z$ to straight half-lines through the origin... (but never achieving $0$ of course).

Comment: Would you say that explanation is sufficient in a paper?

Comment: @Mugge in this website there is a rule that in most cases the full solution should not be given. You should try to understand this solution yourself. If you find this answer as the most helpful be sure to click on the grey button

Comment: @Mugge If "a paper" means a research paper, including any explanation of such a well known triviality would be silly. Otoh if it's a paper for a class you should make certain to explain that you copied the explanation off the internet